# JBoss 7.1.1 + Hibernate Deploy Fail

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss

After Schema Update Complete, the database is created, but I get this error message and deploy fails.

```
16:57:33,133 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."axbi-ear.ear/axbi-ejb.jar#axbiEJBModulePU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."axbi-ear.ear/axbi-ejb.jar#axbiEJBModulePU": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:54) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.registerAttribute(MetadataContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.registerAttributes(MetadataContext.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.populateStaticMetamodel(MetadataContext.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.__createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more

16:57:33,366 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "axbi-ear.ear"
```

I migrate from EclipseLink to Hibernate my entire project. Any clues as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at all the entities I found the problem, some mappings were in error. But Hibernate might have pointed to a specific error ... not this generic NPE.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what kind of error mappings there were ? I have the exact same issue

Comment: Look for wrong '@OneToMany' and '@ManyToOne' mappings, check mappedBy attributes. I dont remember the specific error, sorry.

Comment: Thanks - how come eclipse link did not fail though ?